# Most efficient way to check if timestamp in list exists between two other timestamps?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search a list of datetimes to check if there is a timestamp C that exists between timestamp A and B. I found the bisect stdlib but am not sure how to apply it here with datetime types.

My setup is similar to this:

```
insulin_timestamps = ['2017/07/01 13:23:42', '2017/11/01 00:56:40', '2018/02/18 22:01:09']

start_time = '2017/10/31 22:00:11'
end_time = '2017/11/01 01:59:40'
```

I want to check if a timestamp in the list exists between my two variable times. I am doing this multiple times in a loop. The only solution I can come up with is another loop within it that checks the whole list. I would rather not do that for efficiency purposes as it is a lot of data. Any tips?

Comment: It is impossible to achieve this faster than a single traversal. You can't determine a timestamp without accessing it.

Comment: If your timestamps are sorted, you can do a binary search, which would be a lot  quicker with a large list.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the outer loop code to see if there are any efficiencies that could be made in terms of how the list of timestamps is searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if a timestamp exists between `start_time` and `end_time`, and the list is sorted, then you just need to check the timestamp immediately following `start_time` (assuming it occurs in the list). If that is less than `end_time`, then the result is true. It would add a few checks to the code but would cut runtime in half by removing the need for `bisect_right`. The code would appear as follows:

```
left_index = bisect_left(insulin_timestamps, start_time)
present = (
    len(insulin_timestamps) != 0 # if the list is empty the result is False
    and left_index != len(insulin_timestamps)
    and insulin_timestamps[left_index] < end_time
)
```

Here `left_index != len(insulin_timestamps)` checks that `start_time` is not than any element in the list: if it is, then the result is `False`.

Comment: @Nick thanks for catching my error there! Yes I apologize I immediately realized after posting my comment that it was effectively a full answer anyway so it made more sense to add it here. I suspect for OPs purposes there will be no difference between the two answers, but hopefully someone enjoys the addition.

Comment: It's definitely worthy of an answer.

Comment: @TiannaWrona you should accept this answer instead as it should be even more efficient

Comment: Nick and @kraigolas thank you both so much. I knew it was something with bisect but couldn't put my finger on it. This appears to work at surface level but I am going to check the data tomorrow. Been plugging away all night.

Comment: @TiannaWrona do please consider posting a question with your outer loop code too. If you're iterating start and end times in an increasing manner I suspect the code could be made even more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Since your datetime values are in `Y/m/d H:i:s` format, they can be sorted by regular string comparison, and so you could use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module (assuming `insulin_timestamps` is sorted) to efficiently search for a timestamp in `insulin_timestamps` which is between the `start_time` and `end_time` values:

```py
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

present = bisect_left(insulin_timestamps, start_time) < bisect_right(insulin_timestamps, end_time, sti)
```

Note that if in your outer loop you are iterating start and end times, it might be more efficient to iterate the timestamps array at the same time.

Comment: @TiannaWrona note that I made a minor change to the `bisect_right` call which will also improve the efficiency of this code.